# Write with keyboard into a jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I was wondering if it is possible to write into a JtextArea (java swing) and then catch this String like in a JTextField ?

Comment: Look into a `DocumentListener`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by 'catching' the String? JTextArea has getText and setText methods as well.

Comment: Do you mean updating the JTextField while the JTextArea is updating?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. As you can see on the [Java APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) both components are subclasses of `JTextComponent`, and thus inherit `getText()` and `setText()` methods.

JTextField can be seen as a "simpler" JTextArea, since it behaves very similarly but only has one line of text and no scrolling.